# Flash Builder HTTP service with a space character in the URL?

Tags: flash, url, builder, space, httpservice

I am using Flash Builder 4.6 and I am trying to get a JSON from World of Warcraft API (http://eu.battle.net/api/wow/guild/Lightning's Blade/Myst?fields=members).

This URL in a browser returns perfectly the expected JSON row.

Now in Flash Builder when I try to test this HTTP Service i get the following error:
"InvocationTargetException:Unable to connect to the URL specified"

My first idea was that the space character in the URL its the source of this problem so I tried in the Connect to Data/Service wizard to escape the space with %20 but as soon as I save the new url, it goes back to the normal space.

Whats is the proper way to add a HTTP Services that uses a URL with space character inside it?